# Ignoring exception in command None: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "play" is not found. this happens in python

Tags: python, error-handling, discord, bots

I am trying to make an bot just like rythm and it gives me this error
Ignoring exception in command None:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "play" is not found
Here's the code:

music.py:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl

class music(commands.Cog):
  def _init_(self, client):
    self.client = client
    
    @commands.command()
    async def join(self,ctx):
      if ctx.author.voice is None:
        await ctx.send("You're not in a voice channel!")
      voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
      if ctx.voice_client is None:
        await voice_channel.connect()
      else:
        await ctx.voice.client.move_to(voice_channel)
        
    @commands.command()
    async def disconnect(self,ctx):
      await ctx.voice.client.disconnect()

      @commands.command()
      async def play(self,ctx,url):
        ctx.voice_client.stop()
        FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': 'vn'}
        YDL_OPTIONS = {'format':"bestaudio"}
        vc = ctx.voice_client

        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
          info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
          url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
          source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, **FFMPEGOP_OPTIONS)
          vc.play(source)
          
def setup(client):
  client.add_cog(music(client))
```

Comment: Did you pay attention to proper indentation? The `play` command does not seem to be in the right place

Comment: Still not working...

Comment: @Zempo it looks like your `play` command is defined in the `disconnect` command. This makes it such that the play command would not be visible to the bot.

Comment: Can you help me please then?

Answer (score 0):

If you're setting up your music-related commands in a **music.py** file, I'm assuming you also have a **main.py** file in which you run the bot token and such.

The way I have mine set up is by importing the cog from my separate command files into the **main.py** file.

Instead of doing *this* in your **music.py** file:

```py
def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(music(client))
```

Try putting this in your **main.py** file:

```py
from music import music

client.add_cog(music(client))
```

> (noticed you also have only one underscore `_` in `def __init__` in your code pasted above, it should be two).

It is also good practice in discord.py to name/use your cogs like:

**music.py**

```py
class MusicCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
    self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    # [. . .]
```

**main.py**

```py
from music import MusicCog

client.add_cog(MusicCog(client))
```

As the comments on your original post say, also, the indentation does look off in the way you pasted your code. The `play` command appears to be defined within your `disconnect` command.

On another note, though, if you run into issues with your commands in cogs (I've witnessed a couple of others get a weird issue with it, despite it working for me), you can simply define your commands this way:

```py
client.command()
async def disconnect(self, ctx):
    await ctx.voice.client.disconnect()

client.command()
async def play(self, ctx, url):
    # [. . .]
```

I do recommend using commands in cogs personally, however. It makes it easier to use separate files and keeps your code more organized.

I hope this helps anyone coming across this issue or a similar one.